# Semantic UI sticky module not working

Tags: javascript, css, sticky, semantic-ui

I am trying to make my menu bar sticky but for some reason it doesn't do anything.

As explained on Semantic-UI documentation:

> Sticky content attaches itself to the viewport when it is passed

However my navbar does not stick to the top once it is passed.

Any one know why this is?

Markup:

```
<div id="example1">
    <div class="ui sticky">
      <div style="clear:both" class="ui teal menu">
  <a class="active item">
    <i class="home icon"></i> Home
  </a>
  <a class="item">
    <i class="info icon"></i> About 
  </a>
  <a class="item">
    <i class="book icon"></i> Read
  </a>
  <a class="item">
    <i class="edit icon"></i> Write
  </a>


  <div class="ui right menu">

    <a class="item" id="logIn">
    <i class="user icon"></i> Log In 
  </a>
  <a class="item" href="signup">
    <i class="signup icon"></i> Sign Up 
  </a>

  </div>

</div>
</div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('.ui.sticky')
  .sticky({
    context: '#example1'
  });
  })
```

**EDIT**

Here is a [link](http://talk.hostoi.com/Semantic-UI/examples/index.php) to the site.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you're checking it correctly?

Here's a codepen with your code and it works fine to me:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jEYXGG

This is what I used:

```
<div id="example1">
 <div class="ui sticky">
  <div style="clear:both" class="ui teal menu">
  <a class="active item">
   <i class="home icon"></i> Home
  </a>
  <a class="item">
   <i class="info icon"></i> About 
  </a>
  <a class="item">
   <i class="book icon"></i> Read
  </a>
  <a class="item">
   <i class="edit icon"></i> Write
  </a>
  <div class="ui right menu">
   <a class="item" id="logIn">
    <i class="user icon"></i> Log In 
   </a>
   <a class="item" href="signup">
    <i class="signup icon"></i> Sign Up 
   </a>
  </div>      
 </div>
 ... Added some content here ...
</div>
```

Comment: That is strange, I have checked it on multiple browsers and it does not work for me. Here is a link to the live site http://talk.hostoi.com/Semantic-UI/examples/index.php. Also posted in the edit above. Hopefully someone can find out what is preventing that from happening in my mark-up.

Comment: The #example1 you're using contains only the menu and that's the problem. Notice that in my codepen #example1 contains whole long content. So try declaring sticky without the context or use #home for it.

Comment: I have tried both ways, tried to change the `#example1` so that it contains the whole document and still nothing happens, also tried declaring sticky with `context: '#home';` so it uses the body tag and still nothing happens as you can see from the source code on the live site.

Comment: It does not work for me!